# Exclude rows in mysql which contain a year without the NOT LIKE operator

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a table which contains tags. Almost all tags are genres (such as action and comedy). However there are also tags such as `Winter 2014` and `Summer 2012`. These are seasonal tags.

I want to exclude those tags from a genre listing. So how do I exclude those seasonal tags in the query?

The reason I don't want to use the `NOT LIKE` operator is to prevent full table scans.

This is what I currently have (in eloquent):

```
$genres = Tag::where('slug', 'not like', '%20%')->get()->lists('name');
```

Sidenote: a laravel 4 (eloquent) approach would be appreciated but not necessary.

This is my table

```
+---------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id      | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| slug    | varchar(255)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| name    | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| suggest | tinyint(1)       | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| count   | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+---------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you, I would add `seasonal tinyint(1)` field to this table and now you could simply run:

```
$genres = Tag::whereSeasonal(0)->get()->lists('name');
```

to get tags that are not seasonal.

If you cannot do it, you could store ids of seasonal tags in PHP array (or in one more table) - I don't know how many tags you have and how often you add seasonal tags and then you could get non-seasonal tags:

```
$genres = Tag::whereNotIn('id', $arrayOFSesonalIds)->get()->lists('name');
```

Comment: How fast is `NOT IN` on an array of ~200 seasons? (it won't be that big but just saying)

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a solution to exclude years in data fields that are stored as strings (`CHAR`/`VARCHAR`), `NOT LIKE` is probably the best way to go about it going off of your description of the problem.  If the dates you're checking are `DATE`/`DATETIME`/`TIMESTAMP` you can use the `YEAR()` MySQL function to yank the year out of the field to which you wish to compare.

If not, could you provide the output of `DESCRIBE tablename` for the table on which you wish to perform this action?

Comment: added describe tablename output

Comment: Is it possible to rewrite the `slug` values to start with `$YEAR`?  This would enable you to easily index these queries.  MySQL can't index queries that use leading wildcards.

Comment: The problem is that they don't always start with year. Is there perhaps a `NOT LIKE IN` function? Because there are 4 seasons and the year doesn't really matter. It's just that I need to exclude season tags from the rest. 4 `WHERE` clauses could also work, but a `NOT LIKE IN` would be nice